Create subscription - Walmart API Notification 415 Error
I am trying to make the request API /v3/webhooks/subscriptions from Walmart but it response for me 415 Unsupported Media Type
I have assign Accept and Content-Type is application/json in headers
What should I go next to solve this?

curl --location 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/webhooks/subscriptions' \
--header 'WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN;' \
--header 'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: 4abf82fc-222c-4def-a498-7eadfc36f825' \
--header 'WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace' \
--header 'Authorization;' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'ChannelType;' \
--data '{
    "events": [
        {
            "eventType": "PO_CREATED",
            "partnerId": "",
            "eventVersion": "V1",
            "resourceName": "ORDER",
            "eventUrl": "",
            "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}'

Here is the cURL I make. Please don't pass Content-Type in Header.If you try to call by Postman please try to remove the default value Content-Type is make by Postman

import requests
import json 

data        = { "events": [ { "eventType": "PO_CREATED", "eventVersion": "V1","resourceName": "ORDER", "eventUrl": "your notification url", "status": "ACTIVE"} ]}
url         = 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/webhooks/subscriptions'
headers     = {'Accept':'application/json', 'WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN':'access_token', 'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID':'4abf82fc-222c-4def-a498-7eadfc36f825', 'WM_SVC.NAME':'Walmart Marketplace'}
response    = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data),)
return response.json()


Get the following result

"events": [
    {
    "eventType": "PO_CREATED",
    "subscriptionId": "Subscription id",
    "partnerId": "Partner id",
    "eventVersion": "V1",
    "resourceName": "ORDER",
    "eventUrl": "Event url",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "channelType": "WEBHOOKS"
    }
]


I solve this issue by following  python request  and sample code here. Make sure request body json string

